# Calling Scala code from Java with java.util.List when Scala's List is expected

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

I have written an API in Scala. There are a couple of entry points where I am expecting a List[SomeTrait] as input and returning a List[OtherTrait].

I am including that Jar in a Java project for use and ran into a problem trying to pass a java.util.List to a method expecting Scala's List object. I realize they are not the same and that Java doesn't know how to do the conversion. So, how do you make this work without expecting the Java caller to pass in a Scala List?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would love to hear other suggestions but this is the solution I have found and I couldn't find it anywhere on the Google.

If my normal Scala entry-point is a method that is something like this:

```
def doSomething(things: List[Thing]): List[Result] = { ... }
```

I add another method like this:

```
//import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

def doSomething(things: java.util.List[Thing]): java.util.List[Result] =
  doSomething(things.asScala.toList).asJava
```

The explicit conversion in the call to the original method is because it will end up in an infinite loop calling itself.

This is my first attempt at posting and answering my own question...apologies if I missed some standard way to doing this. It seemed like it was worth sharing and also worth opening up for discussion on better methods as I am VERY new to Scala.

**EDIT** Updated code to reflect suggestion from @Luigi Plinge

Comment: That's exactly the answer I was about to post

Comment: You should ditch the `JavaConversions` and convert the result back to a Java List using `.asJava`

Comment: +1 to Luigi's suggestion, don't use JavaConversions, use JavaConverters and the explicit .asJava/.asScala methods - the implicit conversions can do strange things. Also avoid overloading, create a shim/wrapper to be called from Java instead.

Comment: @Luigi Plinge - You should post this as an answer with an updated version of his code (without the implicit conversion).

Comment: I'm really trying to focus on Scala best-practices. JavaConversions is something to stay away from? That makes sense to me. I updated my answer to reflect (and reference) Luigi's suggestion.

I'm more concerned though about how Java should interact with a Scala library expecting List. @JedWesley-Smith Can you elaborate on your suggestion to avoid overloading?